# How do I get Icloud to back up photos but not videos?

Tags: memory, storage, photos, icloud

My Icloud is full.
How do I get Icloud to back up photos but not videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCloud is an all or nothing synchronization tool.

One workaround is to export the video out of Photos to a file location on an iPhone or Mac so it is stored there locally. At that point, the video will not be backed up in the cloud. You would have to have your own backup so the video is not lost if something were to happen to one of your devices.

To export the video to a file location on the phone, select the video in the Photos app, tap the share icon, and then select Save to Files. Under *On My iPhone* you can create a new folder for videos.

To export a video file on a Mac, you need to open the Photos app, select the video, and then go to *File > Export > Export [number] Videos*.